# JVM Crashes with homebrew openjdk@8 on Mac m1 pro (Java version "1.8.0_345")

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, apple-m1

Here is the crash log

```
10:49:45,752 DEBUG [OpenSsl] Default cipher suites (OpenSSL): [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256]
10:49:45,773 DEBUG [ResourceLeakDetectorFactory] Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@36a35020
10:49:45,789 INFO  [ConnectionPool] [[id: 0xe9a7aa0d, L:/172.31.125.253:55918 - R:identity2-e2e.message-preprod.a.intuit.com/52.32.166.239:6651]] Connected to server
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010b5c255c, pid=25158, tid=0x0000000000023a9b
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_345) (build 1.8.0_345-bre_2022_08_04_23_35-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.345-b00 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x53955c]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/kaishwarya/Developer/apache-tomcat-8.5.81/bin/hs_err_pid25158.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues
```

How should I resolve this? I was just trying to do local setup of monolithic project.
It has been working fine for past 2 months.
I started seeing this suddenly yesterday.

Comment: Start by looking at the error report file.

Comment: You're running x64 JVM on the ARM64 hardware under Rosetta emulation. This is not good both from performance and reliability perspective. E.g., I experienced myself Rosetta related JDK [issues](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8294072) before. I'd suggest to run ARM64 JDK build on M1 Mac.